# Глобальный мьютекс в Linux

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, multiprocessing, mutex

Сразу: Linux не моё, так что, возможно, напишу ерунду и решение давно есть, просто я его не нагуглил...

Имеется расчетная программа, запускается во многих экземплярах, т.е. имеем не многопоточность, а многопроцессность. И все они лезут время от времени в один и тот же файл. В Windows все просто, именованный глобальный мьютекс, и если что — все дружно выстраиваются в очередь.

Теперь надо то же самое посчитать, чтоб побыстрее, на мощном многопроцессорном сервере под Ubuntu. Количество процессов возросло примерно на порядок, так что вопрос синхронизации весьма важен. После бесед с ИИ :) и копания в литературе родился такой файловый глобальный мьютекс:

```
class GlobalMutex {
private:
    int lockFileDescriptor;

public:
    GlobalMutex(const char * lockFilePath) {
        lockFileDescriptor = open(lockFilePath, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
        if (lockFileDescriptor == -1) {
            throw std::runtime_error("GlobalMutex: failed to open lock file");
        }
    }

    ~GlobalMutex() {
        close(lockFileDescriptor);
    }

    void request() {
        if (flock(lockFileDescriptor, LOCK_EX) == -1) {
            throw std::runtime_error("GlobalMutex: failed to acquire lock");
        }
    }

    void release() {
        if (flock(lockFileDescriptor, LOCK_UN) == -1) {
            throw std::runtime_error("GlobalMutex: failed to release lock");
        }
    }

    GlobalMutex()                                = delete;
    GlobalMutex(const GlobalMutex&)              = delete;
    GlobalMutex& operator = (const GlobalMutex&) = delete;

};
```

Не скажу, что он вообще не работает, но судя по результатам, где-то он все же ухитряется пропустить два процесса одновременно, а это категорически непозволительно, одна ночь на сервере уже пошла коту под хвост :( Блокировка файла неатомарна?

Впрочем, это вопрос хоть и интересный, но второй. А первый — как быстренько набросать глобальный мьютекс под Linux с таким вот интерфейсом (да попроще, так как, как я уже писал, я с Linux не очень дружен), чтоб саму программу не переделывать?

Comment: Где лежит файл? Машин много или одна с кучей ядер?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Одна с кучей ядер, весь запуск из своего домашнего каталога, там же и файлы все, и файл данных и блокируемый. Мне бы скорее хочется, чтоб кто-то сказал - это решение верное или нет? Потому что может, причина в другом - все же на Win пять процессов, а тут все 50... Может, я в самой программе что не так написал, и когда 5 процессов, то все нормально, а вот когда 50+...

Comment: Это верное решение. Ищите гонку в другом месте. Или добавьте в вопрос минимальный воспроизводимый пример. Я могу сделать нагрузочный тест у себя.

Comment: Это нерабочий вариант. Нет возможности даже удостовериться, что процессы будут работать с одним и тем же файлом. Используйте https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.mutexes

Comment: @user7860670, даже если во всех процессах имя файла совпадает, рабочий каталог совпадает, файл на локальной файловой системе? Я считал что локальная файловая система крайне надёжная конструкция. Или нет?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Типичная проблема - кто-то удяляет и пересоздает файл, пока он открыт где-то еще, а потом начинаются веселые квесты.

Comment: @user7860670, я думаю что это вечный пустой файл сущестующий только с целью синхронизации. Harry, это так?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Да, это файл-мьютекс, если можно так выразиться. Никто к нему кроме как из этого класса, не лезет. Спасибо за консультацию, просто это был первый кандидат :) За предложение погонять спасибо, но пока не стоит того.

Comment: @Harry, приложение делает fork/exec в состоянии с захваченной блокировкой файла?

Comment: @avp Нет, оно не под Linux'ы писалось, просто запускается типа `nohup ./almus &` 50 раз :) Ладно, мне сейчас переписывать просто некогда, я обходной вариант нашел, можно их поделить и по 3-4 штуки на один файл посадить, а не все 50 на один, и запускать из разных каталогов. Так что теперь это скорее вопрос на будущее, думаю, не последний раз с таким сталкиваюсь...

Comment: Понятно. Но непонятная проблема все равно остается. Только с тремя она будет реже вылезать

Comment: @avp Да. Но мне сейчас важно не столько найти проблему, сколько просчитать всё до понедельника :) А потом уже буду копаться...

Comment: @evo А разве это мьютекс?...

Comment: @evo Мне нужен *глобальный* мьютекс, который работает не между потоками одного процесса, а который работает между процессами.

Answer (score 0):

Вот [тут](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/devel/Foundation/include/Poco/NamedMutex_UNIX.h), через [semop](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=semop&category=2&russian=0) и через [semget](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=semget&category=2&russian=0) [реализован](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/devel/Foundation/src/NamedMutex_UNIX.cpp) именованный мьютекс

Сценарий примерно такой:
Создаем файл - мьютекс:

```
    fd = open(fileName.c_str(), O_RDONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
    _semid = semget(key, 1, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH | IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL);
    semctl(_semid, 0, SETVAL, arg);
```

lock:

```
    struct sembuf op;
    op.sem_num = 0;
    op.sem_op  = -1;
    op.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
    int err;
    do
    {
        err = semop(_semid, &op, 1);
    }
    while (err && errno == EINTR);
```

unlock:

```
    struct sembuf op;
    op.sem_num = 0;
    op.sem_op  = 1;
    op.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
    semop(_semid, &op, 1);
```

Comment: А зачем тут нужен `fd = open(...)`? imho все остальное это типичная работа с System V semaphore, достаточно подробно описанная в [man semget](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/semget.2.html) (и смежных manpages). О работе с более продвинутыми POSIX semaphores можно прочесть в [man 7 sem_overview](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html). / Но это похоже не решит задачу в вопросе, поскольку концептуально flock/lockf делают то же самое (и очень похоже, что поднятая в вопросе проблема будет наблюдаться независимо от конкретного механизма локинга)

Comment: семафоры не могут заменить мьютекс, они не подходят для задачи автора темы